# Convergence and analyticity of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, analyticity

My question is, generally, is there any relationship between convergence and analyticity of a complex-valued function (namely, does one property imply the other etc?)

For example, a function defined by the power-series $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n!z^{n}$ diverges for all $z \neq 0$. So, does the derivative of $f$ at the origin, defined as follows,
\begin{eqnarray} f'(z)|_{z=0} = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z) - 1}{z} \end{eqnarray}
not exist? I.e. $f(z)$ is not analytic at the origin?

Considering this example, does divergence imply non-analyticity? (Equivalently, in other words, analyticity implies convergence?) I've used an example above where a function is defined by power-series but I'd like to know the general answer, as I also deal with functions defined by integrals.

Note on definition: I use the definition that a function is analytic at a point if its derivative exists at that point and in a neighbourhood of that point (equivalent term used is "holomorphic").

Comment: A *series* can be convergent or divergent, not a function. Your function $f$ is *only* defined at the single point $z=0$. Both  $f'(0)$ and $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z) - 1}{z} $ are only defined if $f$ is defined in some neighbourhood of $z=0$.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR What if $f$ is defined on the Riemann sphere i.e. $f : \mathbb{C}P^{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{1}$, then I ask the question is $f$ analytic at zero?

Comment: I don't understand your question. $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n!z^{n}$ is only defined for $z=0$ and nowhere else.

Comment: @MartinR when I say my function $f$ is defined on the Riemann sphere I mean that the domain and range of $f$ include the point at infinity ($\mathbb{C}P^{1} \simeq \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$)

Comment: I know what the Riemann sphere is. But I don't understand how that is related to your infinite series (which converges only in one point, so the value is *undefined* anywhere else).